# interpret \UXXXXXXXX Unicode codes in text file

Tags: unicode

I have the following file :

```
$ cat test
Villes visit\U000000e9es
```

How can I interpret those `\UXXXXXXXX` codes, e.g. how can I get :

```
$ cat test | pipe into something
Villes visitées
```

Comment: That's not a UTF-8 code, that's a C-style representation of a character by its Unicode codepoint. Maybe you mean that you want to replace that `\U000000e9` with it the UTF-8 encoding of the U+00E9 character?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, replace the C-style `\U000000e9` by `é`

Comment: The question is by `é` encoded as per the user's locale? Like as 0xe9 if the locale uses iso8859-1 or as UTF-8 (0xc3 0xa9) regardless of the user's locale?

Comment: I think it's by the user's locale. It's a file that's produced by someone else, thus I don't have all the details. But it's produced using C preprocessor (`cpp`), something like (in its simplest form) `$ echo "villes visitées" | cpp -P`, which prints out `villes visit\U000000e9es`.

Comment: To clarify, `\U000000e9` is unambiguous. That's the LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE character. The question is more about how you want to represent it, so more about how the output will be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -C -pe 's/\\U([[:xdigit:]]{8})/chr hex$1/ge' <yourfile
Villes visitées
```

Assuming the locale uses UTF-8 as its charmap¹, that would convert `\UXXXXXXXX` to the UTF-8 encoding of the U+XXXXXXXX character. To get UTF-8 `O`utput regardless of the user's locale, change the `-C` to `-CO`.

To convert it to the `é` character in the correct encoding for the user's locale (assuming there's such a character in the user's locale charset):

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/\\U([[:xdigit:]]{8})/chr hex$1/ge' <yourfile
```

So for instance, in a `fr_CH.iso88591` locale, that would convert it to the 0xe9 byte (the encoding of `é` in ISO8859-1), while in a `zh_HK.big5hkscs` locale that would convert it to 0x88 0x6d (its encoding in BIG5-HKSCS). And 0xc3 0xa9 in a `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale (its UTF-8 encoding). In a `ar_AE.iso88596` locale, as ISO8859-6 doesn't have a `é` character, you'd get `Villes visit\x{00e9}es`.

Or you could use ICU's `uconv` (in the `icu-devtools` package on Debian-based systems) to apply the [`Hex/C-Any` *transform*](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/transform.jsp?a=hex/c-any&b=Villes+visit%5CU000000E9es) :

```
uconv -x hex/c-any <your-file
```

It understands `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` sequences (more if you use [`hex-any`](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/cldr/2022-08-17/icu4c/source/i18n/unesctrn.cpp#L68)) and outputs in UTF-8. Pipe to `iconv -f utf-8` to get the output in the user's locale (see also `iconv`'s `-c` option to skip characters that can't be encoded).

```
$ printf '%s\n' '&#233; &#xe9; \x{e9} U+00E9 \u00e9 \U000000e9 \U0001F427 \ud83d\udc27' | uconv -x hex/c-any
&#233; &#xe9; \x{e9} U+00E9 é é  
$ printf '%s\n' '&#233; &#xe9; \x{e9} U+00E9 \u00e9 \U000000e9 \U0001F427 \ud83d\udc27' | uconv -x hex-any  
é é é é é é
```

(both also recognise java-style surrogate pairs though that shouldn't occur in your output if it's from `cpp -P`).

For the `perl` one to understand both `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` like `uconv`'s `hex/c-any` does, change the perl code to:

```perl
s/(?|\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4})|\\U([[:xdigit:]]{8}))/chr hex$1/ge
```

`zsh`'s `print` builtin also understands those `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` (does not require all the 4/8 digits) and many more, so you could also do:

```
print -- "$(<your-file)"
```

You'll get an error if there are characters not present in the locale's charmap.

Some `printf` implementations also support them for their `%b` format directive:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(cat <your-file)"
```

Like zsh's `print`, it supports more than just the `\u`/`\U` ones, at least the `\n`/`\b`/`\r`..., the `\0ooo` ones and often more like `\xHH`.

---

<sup>¹ See output of the `locale charmap` command; in locales that use other charmaps, what you get is mostly useless in your case. If all the code points on a line are in the 0x0 .. 0xff range, you get the ISO8859-1 encoding (the byte value of the code point), and if not (if there's at least one code point above 0xff in the line), the UTF-8 encoding (and some warnings about it)</sup>

Comment: I like the `uconv` syntax, short and simple ! Thanks !

Comment: There are a lot of transliterations available in `uconv` as may be seen by executing `uconv -L` but there is no description or any detail in the uconv man page about such transliterations. Where are they explained ?

Comment: @QuartzCristal, deep in the ICU documentation. I'm always dreading getting there.

Comment: This could be of help: https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/transform.jsp?a=Latin&b=%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%8D%CF%82&show=on

Comment: Perhaps we should use `Any-Hex/C` as the (default) `Any-Hex/Java` use surrogate code points for characters not in the plane-0. Yes, `Hex-Any` converts hex codes for other planes, but the reverse (Any-Hex) doesn't.

Comment: The `printf '%b'` use is quite a risky bet.

Comment: Yes, `printf %b` like `print` will expand more than just the `\u`/`\U`s.

Comment: @QuartzCristal, I ended up switching to `hex/c-any` as `hex-any` handles *all* the escapes as generated by all the `any-hex/*`